# Math random in action script3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making a game and I am trying to create an array of the same object falling in multiple spots. I would also like to have them fall at different spots, using the math random. The problem that I am encountering is that the objects (bananas) don't show up on the screen at all. Can math random be used on the y-axis in action script 3? If so, could someone give me an example?
This is what I have in the main program:

```
var numBananas = 20;
var theBananas: Array = new Array();
theBananas = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numBananas; i++) {
var aBanana: banana_fall = new banana_fall();
aBanana.y=-10;
theBananas.push(aBanana);
theBananas[i].setSpeed(-(Math.random()), 5);
```

And this is what I have in the action script class:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class banana_fall extends MovieClip {

        var velX: Number = 0;
        var velY: Number = 0;
        var falling: Boolean = false;
        var gravity: Number = 2;

        public function banana_fall() {
            var timing: Timer = new Timer(20, 0);
            timing.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, moveMe);
            timing.start();

        }

        private function moveMe(event: TimerEvent) {
            this.x = this.x + velX;
            this.y = this.y + velY;

            if (falling) {
                falling=true;
                velY = velY + gravity;
            }
        }


        public function setSpeed(dx, dy) {
            velX = dx;
            velY = dy;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Y starts at zero for top of screen... You already have it at minus 10 pixels, who know what adding more minus with `setSpeed` as `-Math.random` is achieving? I bet it's going even more off-screen. Increase Y (down) not minus it (go up).. Use integers (whole numbers) for X or Y (be aware that `math.random()` can give fractions). a quick [**5 minute**](http://qczma.com/blog/actionscript-3-random) read-up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is within this method:

```
    private function moveMe(event: TimerEvent)
    {
        this.x = this.x + velX;
        this.y = this.y + velY;

        if (falling)
        {
            falling=true;
            velY = velY + gravity;
        }
    }
```

You set negative velocity and **falling** is **false** initially so gravity never works. Your bananas go bananas, they appear above the screen and flee up into the open space of negative **y**.

As a general rule, you need to trace(...) things to understand what's the problem. Also, there's no need to explicitly use **this** in class methods:

```
    private function moveMe(event: TimerEvent)
    {
        x += velX;
        y += velY;

        if (falling) velY += gravity;

        trace("[BANANA] position:", x, y, "speed:", velX, velY);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The bananas clearly are up there, I can see what is happening with the trace. However, they still don't show up on the screen after I implemented all the changes.

Comment: addChild(aBanana); Doesnt look like you are adding it to the display list after you create it.

Comment: @Catalina, the comment above this is (probably) extremely useful.

Comment: That's it! Thank you :)